# How can i setup Apache Shiro session

Tags: java, spring-boot, security, shiro, spring-restcontroller

I have got some web-service. I need to authenticate and get some data, which permits by Apache Shiro. I use Spring Boot and Apache Shiro.

This is my boot class. Service starts and gets settings from file "shiro.ini".

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootTomcatApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {


        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(SpringBootTomcatApplication.class, args);
        }

        @Override
        protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
                    return application.sources(SpringBootTomcatApplication.class);
        }

        private void initSecure(){
                    Factory<SecurityManager> factory = new IniSecurityManagerFactory("classpath:shiro.ini");
                    SecurityManager securityManager = factory.getInstance();
                    SecurityUtils.setSecurityManager(securityManager);
        }



}
```

File "shiro.ini" contains the next settings:

```
cacheManager = org.apache.shiro.cache.MemoryConstrainedCacheManager
securityManager.cacheManager = $cacheManager

sessionManager = org.apache.shiro.web.session.mgt.DefaultWebSessionManager
securityManager.sessionManager = $sessionManager
securityManager.sessionManager.globalSessionTimeout = 1800000

myRealm = com.company.security.MyRealm
```

Controller, which I use for authenticate and get data:

```
    @RestController
    public class HelloController {

            @RequestMapping(value = "auth", method = {RequestMethod.POST})
                    public String auth(@RequestParam("login") String login, @RequestParam("pass") String pass) {
                        return AuthServiceWrapper.auth(login, pass);

            }

            ...//another mappings

    }
```

And my service which send data to another service for authenticate.

```
 public class AuthServiceWrapper{

            private AuthService authService = create(...);

            public AuthService getAuthService(){
                return this.authService;
            }

            public String auth(String login, String pass){
                 SecurityManager securityManager = SecurityUtils.geySecurityManager();
                 ...
                 Subject currentUser = SecurityUtils.getSubject();
                 if ( !currentUser.isAuthenticated() ) {
                    UsernamePasswordToken token = new UsernamePasswordToken(login, pass); 
                    token.setRememberMe(true);
                    currentUser.login(token);
                    currentUser.getSession();
                 }
            }



    }
```

Authentication works nice. I can get data which filters by permissions. But some minutes passed and I need to again authenticate. Please help me how setting session.

Comment: How many minutes? 30?

Comment: 1-2 minutes maximum

Comment: Did you try reducing the `globalSessionTimeout` property?

Comment: 1800000 it is 15 minutes, but it doesn`t work

Comment: 1800000 Is 30 min

Comment: okey, but it doesn`t work

Comment: What are you seeing? What does the session cookie look like?

Comment: I don`t have session cookie

Comment: How are you managing sessions?